# Why is God referred to as male rather than female?

Tags: nature-of-god, gender, gods

Did God choose to reveal his being to us as a male instead of a female or is that something which can be attributed to our understanding? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE! When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent). Unfortunately, I'm voting to close, because this really is a book, not a simple answer. If it helps, I suspect *a* common answer you'll find is "Because in the past, most men wouldn't have listened to a woman" regardless of how wrong headed we now understand that to be. That said, you'll find 100s of answers - and that's the problem.  We expect questions to have *an* answer. This doesn't - this has too many answers, from good to bad

Comment: You should also note that in the bible the term "man" or "men" when used to refer to a large group, stands in the place of humanity - Adam a man was humanity's first representative - So man - represents mankind - aka humanity which includes males and females

Comment: @AffableGeek Other people had godesses, so the point "nobody listens to a female god" can't be quite right. Didn't even Israel at one point worship, among other idol gods, some idol godess?

Comment: Yes, but no culture has s female goddess as the supreme God. Furthermore the point I'm getting at is that there are too many answers, not that that is the right one.

Comment: This question should be closed.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. This question is off-topic and does not fit into one of the [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409) If possible, [edit] this question so that it better fits into one of those question types.

Comment: Why do you think God refers to himself as male? He described his being as non material to Moses saying I am that I am. Or in other words something no man can understand.

Comment: This question can't be answered without specifying a denomination, some believe God has no gender of form, others believe he is a physical man, some believe he has multiple personages, others that He is only one person. Unless you narrow your scope, this question is off topic.

Answer (score 2):

LDS view:

Short answer: Because he is male.

Long answer:

God the Father is male. Before I cite bible scriptures, let me point to the First Vision:

Joseph Smith - History 1:17

> 17 It no sooner appeared than I found myself delivered from the enemy
>   which held me bound. When the light rested upon me I saw two
>   Personages, whose brightness and glory defy all description, standing
>   above me in the air. One of them spake unto me, calling me by name and
>   said, pointing to the other—This is My Beloved Son. Hear Him!

So, Joseph Smith saw God the Father and His Son. If God was anything but male, Joseph would know it. Instead, he taught that Jesus is in the likeness of his father (and therefore a male).

You correctly noted that God revealed himself in male terms. Why not just accept that he IS male, then:

John 14:7-9

> 7 If ye had known me, ye should have known my Father also: and from
>   henceforth ye know him, and have seen him.
>
> 8 Philip saith unto him, Lord, shew us the Father, and it sufficeth
>   us.
>
> 9 Jesus saith unto him, Have I been so long time with you, and yet
>   hast thou not known me, Philip? **he that hath seen me hath seen the
>   Father**; and how sayest thou then, Shew us the Father?

God the Father is a father, and his son looks like him (apparently, that's nothing I could just check). And to be honest, it would be kind of weird if God had revealed himself as female in the OT, and then send an angel to tell her: "I, your female God, will now make you mother of my Son, to whom I will be the father."

---

If this explanation doesn't suit you, then the next reasonable explanation would be that male is, in many languages (not sure about hebrew), the "default" gender. So God revealing himself in female terms would be far more telling than him revealing himself in male terms. Note though that I am not sure which gender is the default in hebrew, but strongly suspect it to be male.

Note also this question: [Is there any biblical justification for referring to God as Mother?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4980/is-there-any-biblical-justification-for-referring-to-god-as-mother)

One of the answers cites Isaiah 49:15 describing the God-People relationship as a mother-child one. Exceptions prove the rule ;-)

Comment: No man hath seen the Father at any time - I respectfully disagree that any man other than Jesus has seen the Father

Comment: @CRags I don't mind if you disagree (as if I expected something else), in that case I point to the last part of my answer.